# Rails: Do Active Jobs survive reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Just exploring the use of Active Jobs in Rails 4 and I am wondering whether an enqueued job will survive a server reboot. The server OS is Linux.

Comment: I can think of a quick way to find out!

Comment: Well, yeah, but I thought surely somebody has already asked the question and had a ready answer.